# Could not set unknown property 'binresultsdir' for object of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.junitplatform.junitplatformoptions

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Getting error message while trying to upgrade java v17 from java v11 using Gradle Wrapper 8.2.1

> Could not set unknown property 'binresultsdir' for object of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.junitplatform.junitplatformoptions

tests.gradle file code for which error is thrown:

```
binResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/acceptanceTest-${profile}-${label}/binary")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated `binResultsDir` [has been removed](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#abstracttesttask_api_cleanup) in 8.X versions of Gradle, consider using `binaryResultsDirectory: DirectoryProperty` property instead.

Read more: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#N30D2A